# JSF h:commandLink JavaScript error

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I am using JSF 2.0 tag `<h:commandLink>` and I'm trying to open an window with `target` as `_blank`. In the target I am trying to populate the document which was fetched from the server. But while doing so I am getting an error in jsf.js (function name is `jsfcljs`) at `f.submit()`.

Declaration is as follows:

```
<h:commandLink id="viewDocument" value="#{template.orderBean.documentBean.documentName}"
               action="#{template.viewCustomDocument}" target="_blank" styleClass="textbold">
    <f:param name="documentId" value="#{template.orderBean.documentBean.documentId}"/>
</h:commandLink>
```

The error I got is

> Object doesn't support this property.

If I use `<h:commandButton>` instead then I am able to call the server and fetch the document.

What can the problem cause be?

Comment: Are you nesting forms? Please show an SSCCE along with exact JSF and servletcontainer impl/version being used so that we (and yourself!) can reproduce the problem by just copy'n'paste'n'running into a completely blank playground project with everything set to default (unless explicitly mentioned otherwise).

Comment: @BalusC I am not nesting the form. There is only one form. One thing that I observed is that, if I submit form by adding some button on the form without action then this commandlink is getting fired properly without any error but if I click on the link it always gives above mentioned error. I would try to give SSCCE so that you will get clean picture.Thanks for the comments :)

Comment: @BalusC I really appreciate your response. I have found out the reason  for the error. That was not due to the commandLink but because there was an component on the page defined with the id=submit so when f.submit() was getting called from jsfcljs it was referring to that button and hence I was getting error. Sorry for the trouble.